# Show tenant Name in address bar

Tags: angularjs, typescript, swagger, multi-tenant

I have a tenant name of school in my DB and when i enter it in the textbox it takes me to the login page but i want my login page address to look something like this

```
localhost:4200/tenantName/account/login
```

right now i am going to login page using this route

```
localhost:4200/account/login
```

The tenantName page is just like the slack website page where they take our organization name first and then take us to login page. I am not working with subdomains right now. I just want my tenantName after the localhost:4200

Comment: with `ngRoute` you can have `.when('/:tenantName/account/login', {` (_also can you guarantee that tenant name is always unique? won't you have collisions with names?_)

Comment: tenantNames will have separate tenant Id's so they won't collide

Comment: ids are not part of the URL though (maybe in the database, but not URL)

Comment: we have designed our database in a way that tenantNames cannot be same.

Comment: my tenancyName value is being retrieved by 'appSession.tenant.tenancyName'. Can i send this value to my routing module file? or is there any other way to do this?